# Fixed vs random effects for panel

Tags: regression, mixed-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I gathered my data into a panel and ran some basic regressions. Most importantly, there is a big difference between the fixed and random effects models.

I used the Hausman test, got a very low p-value, and noted that one model was inconsistent. But which one is it? I like the one with random effects more as the coefficients are closer to my expectations, but is it a good reason to choose that model? What I am looking for is some objective criteria to choose the right approach.

Comment: The choice between including an effect as fixed or random really shouldn't be based on the data. See for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode) for an explanation how they differ. Very briefly, is the effect relevant for your *population* (for example, a male/female dichotomization assuming there's only two sexes) or is it really just a random realization in your sample that might change when you'd repeat the study (for example repeated measures within a specific subject)?

Comment: When the estimates differ a lot, that is evidence to go for the FE estimator. Under the null being tested, both are consistent, while only FE is under the alternative

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Let's consider places A and B. Place A is further away and residents commute to work over a longer distance. In both places people use either cars or bikes, and Y = cars/bikes is higher in place A. I am concerned that this could be due to some factors other than distance, and gather the data for 5 years. I see that the distance travelled by people from both places increases over time; people from place B solve this problem by buying more bikes, whilst people from place A prefer cars. What is the relationship between X which is distance and Y in fixed effects?